# Problems when compiling tex file in sublime text

Tags: miktex, sublime-text

I'm trying to write an article by latex in sublime this morning, but the version of my MiKTeX is too old so I install a new one in the same direction, and then the xelatex builder couldn't work.

When using the traditional builder in LatexTools, it says:
[image]

I also tried the basic builder, which I used before updating MikTeX, and it says
[image]

I have tried the command line in picture 1 and it output a pdf as normal, I have checked my MiKTeX, all the required packages have been installed. But it just couldn't work right in sublime.

Comment: hard to say with no example and no log of the error shown, but make sure that you updated miktex in both user and admin mode ifyou have both installed

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I just deleted the old one and installed a new miktex in the same direction, so I guess it is updated in both mode? I just found that it could be compiled well in TeXstudio, maybe it's some setting problems in sublime?